# What is the optimal value to the NSTimer object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-animation, nstimer

I'm writing some app. I have there some class with custom view. In the view there is timer that is invoking "setNeedsDisplayInRect" method. I need that timer to be very offensive for purposes of the animation (there is no very complex animation). I have set the value for the timer: 0.0001. Is that value not too big? The app is working correctly with it.

Comment: Have you ever seen an animation that rendered at a whopping TEN THOUSAND frames per second? Because that's what you are currently trying to do… Fortunately, neither the runloop nor the drawing system allow you to do that, so you're just burning a **fraction** of the processing cycles you are trying to. Besides that, see rob's or Randall's answers and refrain from using a hammer where a screwdriver would be appropriate.

Comment: that is right)) thought about that, changed it to 1.0/60.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `NSTimer` for this.  Use [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).  It will run at the optimal rate for the device.

Set it up like this:

```
self.displayLink = [self.view.window.screen displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplayForMyView)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and define a method `setNeedsDisplayForMyView`:

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplayForMyView
{
    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.dirtyRect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing animation have you tried Core Animation or UIView Animation? This might make everything a little easier than doing the animation on your own using a timer.